# redirect_back_or_to always redirecting to fallback_location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to use redirect_back_or_to in my app which we recently upgraded to Rails 7, but it never redirects to the referer, always to the fallback location.

This is how the code in my controller looks like:

```
  def set_theme
    if params[:theme]
      current_user.settings(:appearance).theme = params[:theme]
      current_user.save!
    end

    redirect_back_or_to timeline_path
  end
```

I tried doing this:

```
  def set_theme
    if params[:theme]
      current_user.settings(:appearance).theme = params[:theme]
      current_user.save!
    end

    redirect_to request.referer || timeline_path
  end
```

This works as expected.

So, then I looked at the rails source code and copied the whole `redirect_back_or_to` method code into my code (without the options):

```
  def set_theme
    if params[:theme]
      current_user.settings(:appearance).theme = params[:theme]
      current_user.save!
    end
    
    allow_other_host = false
    if request.referer && (allow_other_host || _url_host_allowed?(request.referer))
      redirect_to request.referer, allow_other_host: allow_other_host
    else
      # The method level `allow_other_host` doesn't apply in the fallback case, omit and let the `redirect_to` handling take over.
      redirect_to timeline_path
    end
  end
```

This also works!

I don't understand what is happening here and why it doesn't work when I call the method itself. I can just redirect to the referer when I need to, but I would like to use the function since it already exists.

Comment: is there any before filter method in controller, affecting the functionality?

Comment: No, there is no such thing.